# Invalid or Corrupted License in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, new-project

I have installed Xamarin Studio 5.5.4.

When I want to build the Android project in c# it gives the error "Invalid or Corrupted License".

I could run HelloWork project successfully on my device a couple of hours ago! I just have no clue that why I can't do it now?!

Comment: Contact Xamarin on their support email. The community does not have access to their licensing server to fix stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

Hey it seems this is an old bug, an [example thread](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11959/invalid-or-corrupted-license) from the xamarin forums.
Updating your Xamarin.Android package and installing the latest version of the android sdk should fix this.

Comment: Can u tell me how to update Xamarin.Android? When I go to Xamarin Studio menu-> check for f=updates, there are three packages to be updated. 1.Mono Framework Mdk, Xamarin Studio and Xamarin.ios. (none of which can be updated successfully. They all get failed)

Comment: The three tools I mentioned above finally got updates. But still I get the same errors. :(

Answer (score 0):

@Tina :- hope you have installed xamarin plz follow the step below to update your android SDK.

[***...Windows 7...***]

1. Start button
2. All Program
3. Xamarin
4. Platform Tools
5. Android SDK Manager.

I am going through the same issue still fixing the same. While it is updating the SDK I am replying you.